# HTML Ignoring CSS Tag For Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm learning JavaScript and HTML 5.

I simply cannot get a simple border around the canvas. The html completely ignores the css.

Here's my code:

JavaScript:

```
function buildCanvas()
{
    var w = window.innerWidth / 2;
    var h = window.innerHeight / 2;


    document.write("<CANVAS WIDTH=" + w + " HEIGHT=" + h + " ID=canvas_1>");
    document.write("</CANVAS>");


    drawOnCanvas();
}

function drawOnCanvas() 
{

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas_1");

    if (canvas.getContext)
    {
        var canvas_context = canvas.getContext("2d");

        canvas_context.font = "84px Ariel";
        canvas_context.fillText("Test", 500, 300);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

        <TITLE>Canvas Test</TITLE>

        <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" SRC="scripts/external.js"></SCRIPT>

    </HEAD>

    <BODY onLoad="buildCanvas()">


    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

STYLESHEET:

```
canvas
{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Side-note, the font is spelled Arial. Unless you have a font for mermaids.

Comment: Side-note, don't use document.write.

Comment: document.write was how I learned to add HTML with JavaScript from the tutorial. Is there another way?

Comment: Of course there's another way - see my answer :p `document.write` is a very bad function to be using.

Comment: Right I understand as far as creating tags, but what about when you're adding the html text in between tags?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling `document.write` *after* the document has loaded (ie. during the `onload` event). This replaces the current document with a new one containing your new content. In short, it nukes the page, including style definitions.

Try this instead:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = w;
canvas.height = h;
canvas.id = "canvas_1";
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
```

Comment: I thought onLoad would add it as it loaded, not after it loaded. So I can't use css with html generated by javascript?

Comment: If you read my code, you'll see it's generating HTML, and that it's the use of `document.write` that nukes your page. If you tried `body{background-color:red}` in your css, you'll see that doesn't "work" either with your code ;)

Comment: Right but then where do I write text? i.e. let's say I create a heading using document.createElement, what do I use to write the heading in between the tags if not document.write?

Comment: `document.createTextNode("Your text here")`, then `appendChild` it to the heading. Alternatively, just write HTML ;)